# handling events in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I need to make a login page, when I click the submit button this should be navigated to Dashboard page. The below is my code, what is the problem in it. When I give details in the login page and click on login, the details vanishes and not navigated to dashboard.

```js
import React, { Component, useState  } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { setUserSession } from '../utils/common';
function Login(props) {
    const username = useFormInput('');
  const password = useFormInput('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 
  // handle button click of login form
  const handleLogin = () => {
    props.history.push('/dashboard');
  }
      

        return (
            <form>
                <h3>Sign In</h3>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
                        <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                {error && <><small style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</small><br /></>}<br />
                <input  type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" value={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Sign-in'} onClick={handleLogin} disabled={loading} /><br />
                <p className="forgot-password text-right">
                    Forgot <a href="#">password?</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        );
        }

        const useFormInput = initialValue => {
            const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
           
            const handleChange = e => {
              setValue(e.target.value);
            }
            return {
              value,
              onChange: handleChange
            }
          }
          
           
          export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a route defined for `/dashboard`. Everything worked me in code sandbox without react router setup. Psuedo code shown below

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/dashboard">
    <DashboardComponent />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Where I need to add this code snippet? In the 'handleLogin' ?

Comment: After adding the snippent to my login.js file, now navigation is not happening. But when I give submit button the details of the login remains!